# Assertion error when running GSEApy: assert len(dat) > 1

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I want to prepare a ".cls" file and feed it into the Gseapy software (source code: [here](https://github.com/zqfang/GSEApy/blob/master/gseapy/gsea.py)). I get an assertion error "assert len(dat) > 1". However, my dataframe is >1 so I'm unsure how to rectify my error.

[image]

```
groups = subtype 
with open("./kirp_deg_gene_exp.cls", "w") as cl:
    line = f"{len(groups)}\t2\t1\n#\tKIRP\tnormal\n"
    cl.write(line)
    cl.write("\t".join(groups) + "\t")

gene_sets = ["KEGG_2021_Human", "Reactome_2022", "BioCarta_2016", "WikiPathway_2021_Human", "Panther_2016"]
```

Run GseaPy:

```
gs_res = gp.gsea(data=rcc_normal_deg, # or data='./P53_resampling_data.txt'
                 gene_sets=gene_sets, # or enrichr library names
                 cls= "./kirp_deg_gene_exp.cls", # cls=class_vector
                 # set permutation_type to phenotype if samples >=15
                 permutation_type='phenotype',
                 permutation_num=1000, # reduce number to speed up test
                 outdir=None,  # do not write output to disk
                 method='signal_to_noise',
                 threads=4, seed= 7)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_27/3071075505.py in <module>
      9                  outdir=None,  # do not write output to disk
     10                  method='signal_to_noise',
---> 11                  threads=4, seed= 7)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gseapy/__init__.py in gsea(data, gene_sets, cls, outdir, min_size, max_size, permutation_num, weighted_score_type, permutation_type, method, ascending, threads, figsize, format, graph_num, no_plot, seed, verbose, *arg, **kwarg)
    147         verbose,
    148     )
--> 149     gs.run()
    150 
    151     return gs

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gseapy/gsea.py in run(self)
    258         self.cls_dict = cls_dict
    259         # data frame must have length > 1
--> 260         assert len(dat) > 1
    261         # filtering out gene sets and build gene sets dictionary
    262         gmt = self.load_gmt(gene_list=dat.index.values, gmt=self.gene_sets)

AssertionError:
```

Data:

`rcc_normal_deg.iloc[-4:,-5:-1].to_dict()`

```
{'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': {'ZNF771': '131.6026',
  'ZNF775': '328.4314',
  'ZNF789': '568.6275',
  'subtype': 'KIRP'},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-11A': {'ZNF771': '61.4095',
  'ZNF775': '107.5387',
  'ZNF789': '63.4277',
  'subtype': 'normal'},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-01A': {'ZNF771': '171.2236',
  'ZNF775': '96.9937',
  'ZNF789': '93.5296',
  'subtype': 'KIRP'},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': {'ZNF771': '107.6399',
  'ZNF775': '198.0431',
  'ZNF789': '249.7065',
  'subtype': 'KIRP'}}
```

Comment: Your problem may be here: `groups = subtype`.  Why are you creating a new variable `groups` rather than just using `subtype`? Are you sure `groups` has `len` greater than 0?

Comment: @BillHorvath yeah the `groups = subtype` was awkward, but it was not the problem. The length is 420 (i.e. >1).

Comment: You're adding a tab between the hash (`#`) and `KIRP` in the `line` constructor, and the documentation image you included is inconsistent (the topmost portion of the screenshot has whitespace there, whereas the "Example of a 3 class cls file" portion of the screen shot does not.) I'd try removing that tab, because the source code from the pandas parser that reads csv files suggests the input to the `load_data` function in `gp.gsea` is faulty.  I.e., change `line = f"{len(groups)}\t2\t1\n#\tKIRP\tnormal\n"` to `line = f"{len(groups)}\t2\t1\n#KIRP\tnormal\n"`